# Para qué sirve el return false en el atributo onclick

Tags: javascript, html, html5, seo

Hace unos días me encontré con esta estructura en la etiqueta `a`:

`<a href="https://example.com" onclick="javascript:window.open('https://example.com'); return false;">Text</a>`

Tengo la sospecha de que es para que la fuerza del enlace no traspase Page Rank y así favorecer al SEO que tiene la página que enlaza hacia otra.

¿Google lo detecta como un enlace normal y lo trata como tal o por el contrario está trucado para que no traspase dicho Page Rank por el enlace?

Comment: Hola basicamente el `return false` en javascript o jquery es utilizado en este caso para evitar que el elemento recargue el DOM 

Lo de dices del  SEO  es `rel="nofollow"` espara evitar que el robot de google entre al enlace etc etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Algo asi, pero no tan rebuscado, el `return false;` en este caso se usa para que cuando abra el la URL en otra pantalla no acceda a la url escrita en el HREF, basicamente lo agregan para cancelar el normal funcionamiento del HREF.

El HREF lo dejan completo, en vez de poner `href="#"`, para aquellos que tengan bloqueado el javascript puedan acceder y a efectos del seo para que indexe esa URL.

Comment: ¿Entonces eso pasa pagerank como hace normalmente? ¿Qué sentido tiene hacerlo si es así?